# Determine which object posted a notification?

Tags: cocoa-touch

I'm having trouble identifying how to tell which object posted a notification.

I subscribe to a notification in **object A**:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receivedNotification:) name=@"ReceivedData" object:nil]
```

I post a notification from **object B**:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ReceivedData" object: self userInfo: dict];
```

I recieve the notification in **object A**:

```
- (void) receivedNotification: (NSNotification*) notification
{
   // Method is hit fine, notification object contains data.
}
```

How can I tell that it was **object B** that sent the data and not, for instance, a **object C**?  I need a reference to the sender.  I don't want to add the sender to the notification object being passed, as I am specifiying the sender when I call the notification in **object B**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `NSNotification` class has a method called [object](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNotification/object) that returns the object associated with the notification. This is often the object that posted this notification.

```
- (void) receivedNotification: (NSNotification*) notification
{
   ...
   id myObject = [notification object];
   ...
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want to retrieve. How do I get that in the reciever of my notification?  You can see in my question, the class posting the notification is including object: self.

Comment: Call the `object` method on your notification parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to handle notifications from Class B, then you specify that as the object (which you have left as `nil`) when subscribing to the notification.

With the `nil`, you receive notifications from all objects that post that specific notification.

**edit**

You call `[notification object]` to know what object posted the notification.

Comment: I don't want to limit notifications only to class B, I want to identify the sender of the notification. It doesn't matter where it's coming from. I just need a reference to the object.  I plan to release the object from the notification.

Comment: What's the point in specifying `object: self` in object B if I can't get that information in the receiver of the notification?